# How to edit the value in the dataframe based on a condition in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to add an asterisk (*) to values in a data frame based on condition. I wrote the following dataframe:

| ID | Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 9 | 45.50 |
| B | 20 | 89.99 |
| C | 5 | 14.50 |
| D | 11 | 15.50 |
| E | 9 | 50.99 |

I want to add a (*) to Var2 values if Var1 value is smaller than 10. I wrote the following code:

```
    DF1 = data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C","D","E"), 
                 Var1=c(9,20,5,11,9), 
                 Var2=c("45.50","89.99","14.50","15.50","50.99"), 
    DF1$Var2[DF1$Var1<10] <- paste0(DF1$Var2,"*")
```

The problem is when I do this, I get the following error:

Warning message:
In DF1$Var2[DF1$Var1<10] <- paste0(DF1$Var2,  :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

And the output is the following:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this or have a better method to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to also filter your right hand side to the same number of rows.

```
DF1 = data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C","D","E"), 
             Var1=c(9,20,5,11,9), 
             Var2=c("45.50","89.99","14.50","15.50","50.99"))
DF1$Var2[DF1$Var1 < 10] <- paste0(DF1$Var2[DF1$Var1 < 10],"*")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ifelse()`.

```
DF1 = data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C","D","E"), 
                 Var1=c(9,20,5,11,9), 
                 Var2=c("45.50","89.99","14.50","15.50","50.99")
                 ) 

DF1$Var2 <- ifelse(DF1$Var1 < 10, paste0(DF1$Var2,"*"), DF1$Var2)
```

**output**

```
  ID Var1   Var2
1  A    9 45.50*
2  B   20  89.99
3  C    5 14.50*
4  D   11  15.50
5  E    9 50.99*
```